# make visible responsive menu in all screens?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a bootstrap Nav menu. What I am wondering is instead of showing two buttons on a large screen and when it goes to a small screen showing the nav buttons turn into a hamburger menu. is there a way to make the buttons visible on both small and large screens? I attempted to edit almost all bootstrap.css files to a .d-block class and searched for any .dblock-lg.

```
<div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?= url() ?>">
            <?php if(settings()->logo != ''): ?>
                <img src="<?= UPLOADS_FULL_URL . 'logo/' . settings()->logo ?>" class="img-fluid navbar-logo" alt="<?= language()->global->accessibility->logo_alt ?>" />
            <?php else: ?>
                <?= settings()->title ?>
            <?php endif ?>
        </a>

        <button class="btn navbar-custom-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_navbar" aria-controls="main_navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="<?= language()->global->accessibility->toggle_navigation ?>">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="main_navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">

                <?php foreach($data->pages as $data): ?>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?= $data->url ?>" target="<?= $data->target ?>"><?= $data->title ?></a></li>
                <?php endforeach ?>

                <?php if(settings()->payment->is_enabled): ?>
                    <?php if(\Altum\Plugin::is_active('affiliate') && settings()->affiliate->is_enabled): ?>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?= url('affiliate') ?>"> <?= language()->affiliate->menu ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif ?>
                <?php endif ?>

                <?php if(\Altum\Middlewares\Authentication::check()): ?>

                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?= url('dashboard') ?>"> <?= language()->dashboard->menu ?></a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <img src="<?= get_gravatar($this->user->email) ?>" class="navbar-avatar mr-1" />
                            <?= $this->user->name ?> <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <?php if(\Altum\Middlewares\Authentication::is_admin()): ?>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= url('admin') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-user-shield mr-1"></i> <?= language()->global->menu->admin ?></a>
                            <?php endif ?>

                            <?php if(settings()->links->domains_is_enabled): ?>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= url('domains') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-globe mr-1"></i> <?= language()->domains->menu ?></a>
                            <?php endif ?>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= url('links') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-link mr-1"></i> <?= language()->links->menu ?></a>

                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= url('projects') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-project-diagram mr-1"></i> <?= language()->projects->menu ?></a>

                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= url('pixels') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-adjust mr-1"></i> <?= language()->pixels->menu ?></a>

                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= url('account') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-wrench mr-1"></i> <?= language()->account->menu ?></a>

                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= url('account-plan') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-box-open mr-1"></i> <?= language()->account_plan->menu ?></a>

                            <?php if(settings()->payment->is_enabled): ?>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= url('account-payments') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-dollar-sign mr-1"></i> <?= language()->account_payments->menu ?></a>

                                <?php if(\Altum\Plugin::is_active('affiliate') && settings()->affiliate->is_enabled): ?>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= url('referrals') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-wallet mr-1"></i> <?= language()->referrals->menu ?></a>
                                <?php endif ?>
                            <?php endif ?>

                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= url('account-api') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-code mr-1"></i> <?= language()->account_api->menu ?></a>

                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?= url('logout') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-sign-out-alt mr-1"></i> <?= language()->global->menu->logout ?></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                <?php else: ?>

                    <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="<?= url('login') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-sign-in-alt"></i> <?= language()->login->menu ?></a>
                    </li>

                    <?php if(settings()->register_is_enabled): ?>
                    <li class="nav-item d-flex align-items-center">
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="<?= url('register') ?>"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-sm fa-plus"></i> <?= language()->register->menu ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif ?>

                <?php endif ?>
```

Here is the two different menus for exactly what I'm talking about.
[image: twodifferntbootstrapmenus]

Comment: sure, can do it many ways, from removing navbar-collapse and navbar-custom-toggler classes and implementing your navs with js or own media querys or use a combo of display classes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/ to show different menus etc

Comment: I've already attempted to simply ".d-block" no changes.

Comment: The solution seemed to be Inspect element> find breakpoint which was 992px lg and then go to bootstrap.min.css and search for all breakpoints set at 992 and set the breakpoint smaller.

Comment: rather than changing the vendor file you should really use scss or override it in your styles.css, else it will break when you change the boostrap version, or move to use webpack etc. Is still a bit unclear but you don't seem to have a `.navbar-expand-[sm-md-lg-xl]` which its use is to set when the nav collapses (or not), its mentioned in the docs, literally on the first line https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Yes I was a little unclear. What I have is a script that was built off of a bootstrap template. So bootstrap.min.css sets the media quires obviously. I just figured out how to just change the breakpoints. But yes once it updates it would revert.